# Why am I getting a NaN result from jquery height and width?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get the ratio from the height and width of each image on a page. I keep getting a NaN result and am not sure why.

I have using get() and find()

```
<div class='image-wrapper'>
    <div>
        <img src='views/images/greenstone.jpg' class='row-img'>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src='views/images/home_conch.jpg' class='row-img'>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src='views/images/home_keiki.jpg' class='row-img'>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src='views/images/home_fire.jpg' class='row-img'>
    </div>
</div>

$('img.row-img').each(function() {
    var ratio = $(this).height() / $(this).width();
    console.log(ratio);
});
```

I expect a floating point like 1.234
I get NaN

edit: console log of this returns

```
    Object(1)
    0: <img class="row-img" src="views/images/greenstone.jpg">
    length: 1
    <prototype>: Object { jquery: "3.1.1", constructor: r(), length: 0, … }
```

Comment: Doing a console log of `this` would give hints.

Comment: What do you get if you console log $(this).width and $(this).height

Comment: console log if this returns Object [ img.row-img ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that your script runs before the images are loaded. Therefore their dimensions are undefined.

You can avoid this by running your script in the window *load* event handler

```js
$(window).on('load', () => {
  $('img.row-img').each(function() { ... })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

i suspect your images loading late (async). you logic is oky. just replicating your solution here. remove timeout and see you will get NaN for last image.

```js
setTimeout(function(){

  $('img.row-img').each(function() {
    var ratio = $(this).height() / $(this).width();
    console.log($(this).height() +'/'+  $(this).width() +' = '+ ratio);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='image-wrapper'>
    <div>
        <img src='https://picsum.photos/id/0/500/600' class='row-img'>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src='https://picsum.photos/id/1000/440/350' class='row-img'>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src='https://picsum.photos/id/10/450/370' class='row-img'>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src='https://picsum.photos/id/1003/800/900' class='row-img'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `setTimeout()` is not a reliable method for waiting for resources to load

Comment: agree. only wanted to let asker that if images loads then fire the logic.